# How to see Job agent creation and deletion date in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, sql-server-2014

I created job agent in SQL server 2014 and someone had deleted this without my permission. now my question is that how can I see job agent Creation and deletion date in logs? Is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is NO.You cant find any logs for what happened in the past.But if you want to not be in same situation again.Here is the way to do..

**--Create a server Audit:**

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [SqlAgentObjectAccess_Audit]
       TO APPLICATION_LOG
      WITH
        (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
          ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
    ,AUDIT_GUID = 'e1f7d882-b26e-4b70-bc03-87af197eb7de'
       )
```

**--Now start the server Audit**

```
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [SqlAgentObjectAccess_Audit] WITH (STATE = ON)
```

**---now you need to turn on audit in MSDB and state which events to be audited**

```
USE [msdb]
go 

    CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [SqlAgentObjectAccess_Audit_MSDB]
      FOR SERVER AUDIT [SqlAgentObjectAccess_Audit]
      ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sp_delete_job] BY [dbo]),
      ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sp_delete_job] BY   [SQLAgentUserRole]),
      ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sp_add_job] BY [dbo]),
       ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sp_add_job] BY [SQLAgentUserRole])
      WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

**Note:**
1.You can even login to some share  and read those files daily into table and send an email
2.you can audit a list of all the events available [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms182079.aspx)

References:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2011/02/21/auditing-sql-agent-job-creation-and-deletion/